# Simplify the boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Kindly help in Simplifying Y = BCD + BC'D.

I have been trying to simplify the expression for sometime now, using the the 10 rules but cannot simplify fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the distributive property
\begin{align}
Y = BCD + BC'D = BD(C + C')
\end{align}
Since $C + C'$ is always true
\begin{align}
Y = BD(C + C') = BD(1) = BD
\end{align}
Therefore $Y = BD$.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. Thank you